# select userid from session to insert in the table has created in this session

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie in php and I try to make project for my school

I have to table professeur and class

professeur

```
id--name--lastname--password--email
```

id its a premary key

class

```
id--id_professeur--Nclass--password
```

id is premary key and id_professeur index

and I create a foreign key id_prefessuer reference to id in professeur table

When I create a class I insert Nclass and password but I get this msg:

> Field 'ID_professeur' doesn't have a default value

This my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {<br>
    $cls= $_POST['Nclass'];
    $Password =hash('md5',$_POST['Password']);
    $query ="INSERT INTO `class` (`Nclass`, `password`) VALUES ('$cls', '$Password')";

    $query= mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if ($query == true){
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo(mysqli_error($connect));
    }
}
?>
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: You are trying to insert a new row, but the column `id_professeur` doesn't have any value (and can't be `null`). *So...* you should either `auto_increment` that column, or insert some `id`. It's literally what the error says.

Comment: yes i know but id_prof has a relation with id form prof table

Comment: You should probably enter that into the database then...

Comment: And right from the start: Don't interpolate values into queries, use placeholders!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `class` (`ID_professeur`,`Nclass`, `password`) VALUES (`$_SESSION['whatever_your_key_is for prof id']`,'$cls', '$Password')";
```

note  im assuming you have stored the current professor ID in session

Comment: but how can i get id from session if is stored

Comment: It's written above do one thing use var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: Then just use $_SESSION['the key'] in the statement I gave you

Comment: but when i use that tatement i get an error in sytax

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: remove the ` ` warpping $_session